# Load F# Source File

Tags: f#

How can I load another F# source file (`*.fs`) into a project? The `#load "path/to/file"` preprocessor directive only works if the file you're working from is an F# script file or F# interactive.

I think it may have to do with a makefile, am I correct?

EDIT: Also, I'm not using any IDE; just Emacs, and Mono.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If so, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0572c5b

Comment: No, I'm developing from the command line with Emacs and Mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're compiling manually at the command line, you must list all the files you want the F# compiler to use, in order.

Otherwise, the .NET equivalent to a makefile is [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and the Mono version of MSBuild is [XBuild](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build).